# Decoding anagram with recursive function doesn't give expected output

Tags: php, function, dictionary, recursion, anagram

So I'm trying to decode an anagram into words from my dictionary file. But my recursive function isn't behaving like I'm expecting.

The thoughts about the code is to eliminate letters as they are used on words and output me the string it came up with.

```
function anagram($string, $wordlist)
{
    if(empty($string))
        return;
        
    foreach($wordlist as $line)
    {
        $line = $org = trim($line);
        $line = str_split($line);
        sort($line);
            
        foreach($line as $key => $value)
        {
            if($value != $string[$key])
            {
                continue 2;
            }
        }
        
    echo $org . anagram(array_slice($string, count($line)), $wordlist); 
    }
        
    echo PHP_EOL;
        
}


$string = "iamaweakishspeller";
$string = str_split($string);
sort($string);
    
$file = file('wordlist');
    
anagram($string, $file);
```

This is my result for now, it looks awful, but I'm having some issues with the code - it's going into an indefinite loop with the same roughly 200 words from the word list.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to do with the call inside the function: `anagram(array_slice($string, count($line)), $wordlist)`? I mean you just want to see if your anagram is in your file of words, right?

Comment: @Rizier123, no, the anagram can be multiple words combined as a sentence.

Comment: @Repox So you have text which can contain multiple anagram words which are saved in your file and you want to find all of them?

Comment: @Rizier123, correct.

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: @Rizier123, I'm actually still testing your response against the actual word list and it's running on it's 37th hour (the wordlist has 100k words).With a smaller word list, your solution works brilliant, so I'm assuming it works and I'll accept your answer. Thank you for the time and detailed response you gave.

Comment: Oh wow 37 hours, okay. Hope everything works well :)  The anagram must be huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Situation

You have a dictionary(file) and an anagram which contains one or multiple words. The anagram doesn't contain any punctuation or letter case of the original word(s).

Now you want to find all true solutions where you use up all characters of the anagram and decode it into word(s) from the dictionary.

> **Note:** There is a chance that you find multiple solutions and you will never know which one the original text was and in which order the words were, since the characters of multiple words are mixed in the anagram and you don't have punctuation or the case of the letters in it.

### Your code

The problem in your current code is exactly that you have multiple words mixed together. If you sort them now and you want to search them in the dictionary you won't be able to find them, since the characters of multiple words are mixed. Example:

```
anagram  = "oatdgc"  //"cat" + "dog"
wordList = ["cat", "dog"] 


wordListSorted    = ["act", "dgo"]
anagramSorted     = acdgot
                    ↓↓↓
WordListSorted[0] → cat   ✗ no match
WordListSorted[1] → dog   ✗ no match
```

---

## Solution

First I will explain in theory how we construct all possible true solutions and then I explain how every part in the code works.

### Theory

So to start we have an anagram and a dictionary. Now we first filter the dictionary by the anagram and only keep the words, which can be constructed by the anagram.

Then we go through all words and for each word we add it to a possible solution, remove it from the anagram, filter the dictionary by the new anagram and call the function with the new values recursively.

We do this until either the anagram is empty and we found a true solution, which we add to our solution collection, or there are no words remaining and it is not a possible solution.

### Code

We have two helper functions `array_diff_once()` and `preSelectWords()` in our code.

`array_diff_once()` is pretty much the same as the built-in `array_diff()` function, except that it only removes values once and not all occurrences. Otherwise there isn't much to explain. It simply loops through the second array and removes the values once in the first array, which then gets returned.

```
function array_diff_once($arrayOne, $arrayTwo){
    foreach($arrayTwo as $v) {
        if(($key = array_search($v, $arrayOne)) !== FALSE)
            array_splice($arrayOne, $key, 1);
    }

    return $arrayOne;

}
```

`preSelectWords()` takes an anagram and a word list as argument. It simply checks with the help of `array_diff_once()`, which words of the word list can be constructed with the given anagram. Then it returns all possible words from the word list, which can be constructed with the anagram.

```
function preSelectWords($anagram, $wordList){
    $tmp = [];
    foreach($wordList as $word){
        if(!array_diff_once(str_split(strtolower($word)), $anagram))
            $tmp[] = $word;
    }

    return $tmp;

}
```

Now to the main function `decodeAnagram()`. We pass the anagram and a word list, which we first filter with `preSelectWords()`, as arguments to the function.

In the function itself we basically just loop through the words and for each word we remove it from the anagram, filter the word list by the new anagram and add the word to a possible solution and call the function recursively.

We do this until either the anagram is empty and we found a true solution, which we add to our solution array, or there are no words left in the list and with that no possible solution.

```
function decodeAnagram($anagram, $wordList, $solution, &$solutions = []){

    if(empty($anagram) && sort($solution) && !isset($solutions[$key = implode($solution)])){
        $solutions[$key] = $solution;
        return;
    }

    foreach($wordList as $word)
        decodeAnagram(array_diff_once($anagram, str_split(strtolower($word))), preSelectWords(array_diff_once($anagram, str_split(strtolower($word))), $wordList), array_merge($solution, [$word]), $solutions);

}
```

**Code**

```
<?php

    function decodeAnagram($anagram, $wordList, $solution, &$solutions = []){

        if(empty($anagram) && sort($solution) && !isset($solutions[$key = implode($solution)])){
            $solutions[$key] = $solution;
            return;
        }

        foreach($wordList as $word)
            decodeAnagram(array_diff_once($anagram, str_split(strtolower($word))), preSelectWords(array_diff_once($anagram, str_split(strtolower($word))), $wordList), array_merge($solution, [$word]), $solutions);

    }

    function preSelectWords($anagram, $wordList){
        $tmp = [];
        foreach($wordList as $word){
            if(!array_diff_once(str_split(strtolower($word)), $anagram))
                $tmp[] = $word;
        }

        return $tmp;

    }

    function array_diff_once($arrayOne, $arrayTwo){
        foreach($arrayTwo as $v) {
            if(($key = array_search($v, $arrayOne)) !== FALSE)
                array_splice($arrayOne, $key, 1);
        }

        return $arrayOne;

    }



    $solutions = [];
    $anagram = "aaaeeehiikllmprssw";
    $wordList = ["I", "am", "a", "weakish", "speller", "William", "Shakespeare", "other", "words", "as", "well"];
             //↑ file("wordlist", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)

    decodeAnagram(str_split(strtolower($anagram)), preSelectWords(str_split(strtolower($anagram)), $wordList), [], $solutions);
    print_r($solutions);


?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Iaamspellerweakish] => Array
        (
            [0] => I
            [1] => a
            [2] => am
            [3] => speller
            [4] => weakish
        )

    [ShakespeareWilliam] => Array
        (
            [0] => Shakespeare
            [1] => William
        )

)
```

<sub>(Ignore the keys here, since those are the identifiers of the solutions)</sub>

Comment: I thank you for your effort, but this doesn't work. I only get the sorted anagram string out.

Comment: Well, I just took the exact code you made and put in the correct word file and the anagram and the exact result I get is `Original: a Anagram: aaaeeehiikllmprssw` - nothing else. I know that the Answer to that anagram is `Willam Shakespeare` and that both "words" exist in the wordbook, I get the result mentioned before.

Comment: @Repox Well then it will be way more complicated when you already mixed both words together in you anagram and removed the punctuation, since you now can have multiple matches since you mixed everything together.

Comment: That is the actual problems. Punctuation and whitespaces are not a part of an anagram. The original anagram with whitespaces is `I am a weakish speller` which then can be converted to `William Shakespeare`.

Comment: @Repox Just to make sure and make it clear: The anagram has no punctuation in it and ignores the case of the original word, correct?

Comment: An anagram doesn't work with punctuation; the letters in the anagram can be converted to a single or more words.

Comment: @Repox Now if you have such an anagram there is a chance that it finds different words in it. Now do you want all possible words which are inside the anagram, e.g. anagram= `xySPELLERxySOMETHING` solution = `["speller", "solution", ...]` or do you want only solutions which use every character inside the anagram, so for the example it wouldn't find a solution, since with `xy` it can't find a word?

Comment: Well, it's okay if it finds different words in it, but it's only a true anagram if all characters has been used. Therefore, it wouldn't be a true solution to the anagram if you just converted `I am a weakish speller` to `keep whale alarms` and left out `iis`. There can be multiple solutions to an anagram, but not necessarily.

Comment: @Repox I have edited my entire answer. Now it should work for you.